# Mouse scroll wheel becomes jumpy after a year

Tags: windows-10, mouse, scrolling

I have used multiple mice over the years with my PC from multiple brands. However, all of them start to have scrolling issues after about a year of use.

I have tweaked all the settings in my PC. Cleared any dirt on the scroll wheel after opening the mouse. However, nothing seems to work.

Why does this keep happening specifically to me. Other family members also have their own mice of the same brand that I use but their scroll wheel keeps working as expected.

What could be the possible causes for my mouse wheel becoming jumpy?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Only you can answer this by comparing your working environment
and habits with your other family members.

Some pointers :

- Working surface : Table top and mouse pad
- Force used when moving the mouse (perhaps you need a more robust one)
- Cleanliness of the mouse surface
- Accidents, such as the mouse falling to the floor.

Comment: Also price tags. Higher price doesn't guarantee better build quality, but low price more than likely implies poor quality.